# Wondering about ADT abstract data classes in Python

Tags: data-structures, data-types

I am trying to learn a little Python by myself and came accross this book **Data Structures and Algorithms Using Python** Rance D. Necaise 2011 , to get some proper/formal/correct definitions/terminology in Computer Programming Languages.

First pages introduce Data Structure and Abstract Data Types , and at some point quote :

> No matter which data structure we use to implement an ADT, by keeping
> the implementation separate from the definition, we can use an abstract data type
> within our program and later change to a different implementation, as needed,
> without having to modify our existing code

Is it correct to assume that the above : *'without having to modify our existing code'*  is correct ONLY and as long as my new ADT will provide the same interface of the old one indipendently of the data structures used to create it ?

Comment: There issue is this glitch in the terminology Modifying the interface of an ADT *is* modifying the type. "Keeping the interface" means there is nothing like *my new ADT*, it is still the old ADT.

Comment: @DocBrown , thanks I do get that. But that's why I was asking, I know only Python and I was thinking about using a List() instead of a Dict() ; they don't have the same methods , so I'll have to modify my code to use one instead of the other, unless ,my ADT its a Class object that expose the same interface but then could I name an Object as an ADT  , Objects seem to me all except Abstract

Comment: @DocBrown , feel free to modify my question adding a note that 2 ADTs are the same as long as they behave the same way to the outside, or use your comment to clarify ion an answer, I'll be happy to upvote it

Comment: I think [J_H's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/450781) is fine, I see no need to write another one. And I would not modify your question as it is written now, could too easily invalidate J_H's answer. If you had the terminology right from the start, there would probably not much left which requires an answer.

Comment: think I am mixing up abstract data type and structures. Of course a List is a different type from a Dict.

Comment: Yep in the next pages is stated : 'The abstract data types defned in the text will be implemented as Python classes.' ,

Comment: more on that In Python, the term “class” is essentially synonymous with “type”, so “what is the class of foo” is the same as saying “what is the type of foo”. However the two terms are not synonyms when used in code. type can be used to determine the type of an object, while class is used to define new types.

Comment: Classes are the Python representa on for “Abstract Data Types,” (ADT) a very useful no on in any programming language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that assumption is correct.

An ADT is simply an **interface**,
a [contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract)
for what caller should supply beforehand and can rely on afterward.
Any implementation that conforms to the interface should
be indistinguishable, from the caller's perspective.

Now, that said, of course "abstractions leak".
Caller might notice that a given implementation has certain
effect on the elapsed global clock, or it pre-populates some cache,
or it calls a PRNG some number of times.
Such side effects usually aren't part of the explicit contract,
but calling code might notice it and come to rely on such behavior.
If we swap out a component with another,
which conforms to the public API,
callers shouldn't care, but they might possibly want
side effects from the the informal API they were incorrectly using.
Buggy calling code like this should be fixed,
as failing to obey the interface is a code defect.